# Convert .pug to .ejs

Tags: pug, ejs

can anyone help me convert this .pug code to .ejs code? 
Thank you all for help

```
html  
  head
    title= title
  body
  h1=title
    ul
    each image in images
        li 
            img(src=image width=300)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. Writing in .ejs is pretty similar to basic html with javascript snippets appearing here and there.

```ejs
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<h1><%= Title %></h1>
<ul>
  <% for(let image of images) {%>
     <li><img width="300" src="<%= image %>"/></li>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks man. I just had to change Title to all lower cases and it works perfectly.